# formatting jquery js.erb question

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I make this on multiple lines. I tried but it does not work.

```
$('#wall-top').after("<div id='buttons' style='display: block;'><%=escape_javascript(link_to (image_tag 'btn-post-greeting.png', :width => '241', :height => '68', :alt => 'Btn Post Greeting', :id => 'BtnBoxGreeting'), new_greeting_path, :remote => true) %><%=escape_javascript(link_to (image_tag 'btn-invite-friends.png', :width => '245', :height => '68', :alt => 'Invite Friends', :id => 'BtnBoxFriends'), new_greeting_path, :remote => true, :style => 'display: block;') %></div>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull the ERB chunks out into separate JavaScript variables, format the ERB any way you want, and then paste it all together in JavaScript land. Perhaps something like this:

```
var greet = '<%=escape_javascript(
    link_to(
        image_tag('btn-post-greeting.png', 
            :width  => '241',
            :height => '68',
            :alt    => 'Btn Post Greeting',
            :id     => 'BtnBoxGreeting'
        )
    ), 
    new_greeting_path, 
    :remote => true
) %>';
var invite = '<%=escape_javascript(
    link_to(
        image_tag('btn-invite-friends.png', 
            :width  => '245',
            :height => '68', 
            :alt    => 'Invite Friends',
            :id     => 'BtnBoxFriends'
        )
    ), 
    new_greeting_path, 
    :remote => true, 
    :style  => 'display: block;'
) %>';

$('#wall-top').after(
      '<div id="buttons" style="display: block;">'
    + greet
    + invite
    + '</div>'
);
```

That should get you started. I'd go a bit further and move the `style` attributes into your style sheet; that would cut down on the noise and give you a cleaner separation of concerns.

Comment: You are a rock start. Thanks soooo very much